# How can i show my splash screen first without making in Mainacitivity

Tags: android, splash-screen

I made a splash screen class name **Splash.class** . I didnt make in mainacitivity so how i can I show this at first screen (Opening screen or first screen)

**Manifest**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LoginApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".second"
            android:exported="true"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I think this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebase/splash) can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your manifest like this

```js
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LoginApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".second"
            android:exported="true"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.your.package.Splash" //put yout class here
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

First time your android will run activity with category LAUNCHER, so change your activity class in category.LAUNCHER with your class (Splash.java)

Answer (score 1):

In order to launch the splash screen first, you have to specify the type of intent by using `<intent-filter>`. So, adding the below attributes to the activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file will make it launch first:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

In the end, your manifest will look something like this:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LoginApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".second"
            android:exported="true"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
       
    </application>

</manifest>
```